# How to customize hovertemplate in px.scatter_matrix?

Tags: python, r, pandas, plotly-python

I have recently started to produce scatterplot matrices via plotly.express. The plots reference custom data through a specialized hovertemplate. Here is an example:-

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('./table.csv',dtype={'node':str,'ref_name':str,'population':int,'percent_use':float},keep_default_na=False,sep='\s\;\s',engine='python')
fig = px.scatter_matrix(df,
 dimensions=['area', 'leakage', 'switch_power', 'internal_power', 'max_fall_drive', 'max_rise_drive'],
 color='dont_use_status',
 color_continuous_scale=px.colors.sequential.Bluered,
 symbol='dont_use_status',
 custom_data=['ref_name', 'population', 'percent_use', 'dont_use_status']
)
fig.update_traces(diagonal_visible=True,marker=dict(size=5))
fig.update_traces(hovertemplate=('<b>x: %{x}</b><br>'+'<b>y: %{y}</b><br>'+'<b>ref_name: %{customdata[0]}</b><br>'+'<b>population: %{customdata[1]}</b><br>'+'<b>percent_use: %{customdata[2]:.3f}</b><br>'+'<b>dont_use_status: %{customdata[3]}</b><br>'+'<extra></extra>'))
```

...and it works as intended; however, there is one little detail I cannot figure out: how do I replace the "x:" and "y:" in the hovertemplate with the actual x and y label names? Because it is a matrix, the x and y labels obviously change as you hover from one scatterplot to the next. I cannot seem to find the right keywords when searching. What %{} declaration is needed to dynamically retrieve the x axis and y axis labels?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Oy, found the answer right after posting. I need...

```
fig.update_traces(hovertemplate=('<b>%{xaxis.title.text}: %{x}</b><br>'+'<b>%{yaxis.title.text}: %{y}</b><br>'+'<b>ref_name: %{customdata[0]}</b><br>'+'<b>population: %{customdata[1]}</b><br>'+'<b>percent_use: %{customdata[2]:.3f}</b><br>'+'<b>dont_use_status: %{customdata[3]}</b><br>'+'<extra></extra>'))
```

...which is working.